# How to override renderItem item based in SectionList React Native to use section based?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, facebook

According to FB docs, you can override the renderItem default, item based, render to use the section based render in the SectionList in react native, but I haven't found a way to do that. Please help.

[Here is the link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist#requiredrenderitem)

Answer (score 0):

I only have a workaround, I haven't found a way to make *renderItem* prop render per section instead of per item.

For all sections, you want to render horizontally, use a *FlatList* and set the data for that section to be an array of arrays.
Keep in mind that for listItems you want to render vertically, the *data* property should **NOT** be an array of arrays.

Here's a sample data structure

```
const DATA = [
    {
      header: '30 - 40% Off',
      type: 'horizontal',
//horizontal list here.... As stated above, data is an array that contains an array of the actual data
      data: [
        [
          {
            imgUri:
              'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1607930231879-36bbb29ffe0a',
            store: 'Asanka Store',
            storeRating: '4.4',
            originalPrice: '10.00',
            discountedPrice: '5.00',
          },
          {
            imgUri:
              'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583506522440-b2639ef4c1d8',
            store: 'Maame Dorkono Shop',
            storeRating: '3.8',
            originalPrice: '27.00',
            discountedPrice: '18.99',
          },
          {
            imgUri:
              'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1610397962076-02407a169a5b',
            store: 'Thywill Store',
            storeRating: '3.8',
            originalPrice: '27.00',
            discountedPrice: '18.99',
          },
        ],
      ],
    },
    {
      header: 'All Stores',
    //Vertical List here
      data: [
        {
          imgUri:
            'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598965675045-45c5e72c7d05',
          store: 'Thywill Store',
          storeRating: '3.8',
          originalPrice: '27.00',
          discountedPrice: '18.99',
        },
        {
          imgUri:
            'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1574137907555-8e9ad5bc17fa',
          store: 'Asanka Store',
          storeRating: '4.4',
          originalPrice: '10.00',
          discountedPrice: '5.00',
        }
      ],
    },
  ];
```

Now use that in your SectionList.
We're going to use a FlatList to render the horizontal list.

```
<SectionList
      sections={DATA}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
      renderSectionHeader={({section}) => (
        <Text>{section.header}</Text>
      )}
      renderItem={({section, item}) => {
        return section.type === 'horizontal' ? (
          <FlatList
            horizontal
            data={section.data[0]}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.store + index}
            renderItem={({item}) => <Item item={item} />}
          />
        ) : (
          <Item item={item} />
        );
      }}
    />
```